# R-neuralnet: does it randomize the data?

Tags: r, neural-network

I need to know if the data for training that is passed in the neuralnet call is randomized in the routine or does the routine uses the data in the same order that is given. I really need to know this info for a project that I am working on, and I have not being able to figure it out by looking at the source.

Thnx!

Comment: You should mention which package you're using (I assume `neuralnet`). You could also avoid the issue by explicitly randomising your dataset rows before you fit the model.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, i am using the neuralnet package. I usually randomize the dataset before the fitting, but the thing is that for some runs that I am doing I need the routine to use the dataset exactly as I provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the code - thats one of the most important advantages of FOSS: you can actually check what it is doing (neuralnet is pure R, so you don't even need to fear that you need to dig into FORTRAN or C code, and you can use `debug` to step through the code with example data to get an overview).

Moreover, if necessary, you can even introduce e.g. a new parameter that allows you to switch off randomization if needed.

Possibly `maintainer ("neuralnet")` would be willing to help  you as well (and able to answer much faster than about everyone else here on SE).

Comment: I didn't know about maintaner(), so I used it and contact the person, who replied to me in just a couple of hours! For future reference, neuralnet does not randomize the data, it is used as sent in the call.